# Having trouble passing list as argument in c#

Tags: c#, list, winforms

I'm having issues trying to pass a list as an argument. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. In the following I have an AssociatedTexts list that I am adding to a Books list with the addBook function. The AssociatedTexts that are being selected aren't being saved and assigned to that specific list item in the Books list.

```
Book dictionary = new Book(ID, textBox1.Text, Product.AssociatedTexts);

    Inventory.addBook(dictionary);
```

The addBook function looks like this:

```
    public static void addBook(Book dictionary)
{
    Books.Add(dictionary);
}
```

And here's the constructor for Book:

```
 public Book(int bookID, string name, BindingList<Book> assocText)
{
    BookID = bookID;
    Name = name;
    AssociatedTexts = assocText;
}
```

You requested the entire Book class so here it is:

```
public class Book
{
    public static BindingList<Text> AssociatedTexts { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public int BookID { get; set; }
public int TextID { get; private set; }



public Book()
{

}

public Book(int bookID, string name)
{
    BookID = productID;
    Name = name;
}

public Book(int bookID, string name, BindingList<Text> assocText)
{
    BookID = bookID;
    Name = name;
    AssociatedTexts = assocText;


}
public static void addAssociatedTexts(Text text)
{
    AssociatedTexts.Add(text);
}

public static bool removeAssociatedText(int textID)
{
    bool ret = false;
    if (Book.AssociatedTexts.Count > textID)
    {
        Book.AssociatedTexts.RemoveAt(textID);
        ret = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}

public Part lookupAssociatedTexts(int searchPart)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < AssociatedTexts.Count; i++)
    {
        if (AssociatedTexts[i].TextID == searchPart)
        {
            return AssociatedTexts[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is for each entry in the list of Books to have it's own list of AssociatedTexts. I am mapping these onto datagridviews and the user is able to add their own books with their own varying associatedtexts onto it but I am having trouble associating each associatedtexts list with each Book

Comment: Can you show us the complete code of the Book class? As Book is a model class, it should not contain UI specific stuff like BindingList.

Comment: @KlausGütter I updated it per your request

Answer (score 0):

As each book shall have its own list of associated texts, `AssociatedTexts` must not be static. Otherwise, all books will share the same list.

Also, I suggest to replace BindingList by List as Book is a typical model class and should not contain such UI-related members.

```
public class Book
{
    public List<Text> AssociatedTexts { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    public Book(int bookID, string name, IEnumerable<Text> assocText)
    {
        BookID = bookID;
        Name = name;
        AssociatedTexts = assocText.ToList();
    }

    public void addAssociatedText(Text text)
    {
        AssociatedTexts.Add(text);
    }

    public bool removeAssociatedText(int textID)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        if (AssociatedTexts.Count > textID)
        {
            AssociatedTexts.RemoveAt(textID);
            ret = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public Part lookupAssociatedTexts(int searchPart)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AssociatedTexts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (AssociatedTexts[i].TextID == searchPart)
            {
                return AssociatedTexts[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```